# Unit testing Twilio Flex custom components is throwing errors

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, twilio, twilio-flex

I am currently trying to implement a component for Twilio Flex I am using the Twilio Flex V2 UI. In the creation of the components I am creating there is some buiness logic, that I would like to unit test with jest. However when I try to run the unit test with the jest runner, I am facing the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    > 1 | import { styled } from '@twilio/flex-ui';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        | ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      2 | export const ConfirmationDialogStyles = styled('div')({});                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      3 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      4 |
```

The stack trace is suggesting that the `twilio-flex-ui-core` package is trying to call a method called `playInitialAudio` the stack trace is as follows:

```
Error: Not implemented: HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play
        at module.exports (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\not-implemented.js:9:17)
        at HTMLAudioElementImpl.play (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLMediaElement-impl.js:118:5)
        at HTMLAudioElement.play (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\generated\HTMLMediaElement.js:148:60)
        at e.playInitialAudio (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:337013)
        at new e (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:336838)
        at e.initMediaManager (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:335545)
        at new e (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:335357)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:336285)
        at n (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:363)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:334570)
        at n (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:363)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:171456)
        at n (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:363)
        at C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:1170
        at C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:1180
        at C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:81
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui-core\bundle\twilio-flex-ui-core.prod.js:137:228)
        at Runtime._execModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1439:24)
        at Runtime._loadModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1022:12)
        at Runtime.requireModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:882:12)
        at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1048:21)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:1624)
        at i (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:606)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:574147)
        at i (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:606)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:896189)
        at i (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:606)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:894315)
        at i (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:606)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:892013)
        at i (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:606)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:195038)
        at i (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:606)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:890907)
        at i (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:606)
        at C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:1587
        at C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:1598
        at C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:81
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\@twilio\flex-ui\bundle\twilio-flex.prod.js:137:220)
        at Runtime._execModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1439:24)
        at Runtime._loadModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1022:12)
        at Runtime.requireModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:882:12)
        at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1048:21)
        at Object.require (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\src\components\ConfirmationDialog\ConfirmationDialog.Styles.ts:1:1)
        at Runtime._execModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1439:24)
        at Runtime._loadModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1022:12)
        at Runtime.requireModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:882:12)
        at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1048:21)
        at Object.require (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\src\components\ConfirmationDialog\ConfirmationDialog.tsx:6:1)
        at Runtime._execModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1439:24)
        at Runtime._loadModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1022:12)
        at Runtime.requireModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:882:12)
        at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1048:21)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\src\components\ConfirmationDialog\__tests__\ConfirmationDialog.spec.tsx:7:1)
        at Runtime._execModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1439:24)
        at Runtime._loadModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1022:12)
        at Runtime.requireModule (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:882:12)
        at jestAdapter (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapter.js:77:13)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
        at runTestInternal (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:367:16)
        at runTest (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:444:34)
        at Object.worker (C:\Development\Simplifi.Continuity\plugin-cet-flex\node_modules\jest-runner\build\testWorker.js:106:12) {
      type: 'not implemented'
    }
```

I have setup my compontent following the recommended guidlines from Twilio in the following structure:

```
  |
  |-- components/
  |-- |-- ConfirmationDialog/
  |-- |-- |-- ConfirmationDialog.Container.ts
  |-- |-- |-- ConfirmationDialog.Styles.ts
  |-- |-- |-- ConfirmationFialog.tsx
```

I can provide the code should that be necessary to help answer the question, my unit test though currently looks like the below, I am attempting to create a snapshot of the page and compare the result again the snapshot, but I cannot seem to get past the above error:

```
/*
*   @jest-environment jsdom
*/

import React from 'react';
import { create, act } from 'react-test-renderer';
import ConfirmationDialog, { DialogPromptProps } from '../ConfirmationDialog';

const dialogPromptProps: DialogPromptProps = {
    isOpen: true,
    title: "testTitle",
    message: "testMessage",
    actionText: "Confirm",
    onClose: () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    onConfirm: () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    cancelText: "Cancel",
};

describe("ConfirmationDialog", () => { 

    it("should render the dialog to the screen", () => {
        const render = create(<ConfirmationDialog {...dialogPromptProps} />)
        const root = render.root;

        expect(root).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Based on reading other issue that seemed similar to this, I have attempted to mock the Twilio flex library

```
    beforeAll(() => {
        jest.mock('twilio-flex');
    })
```

or the specific library

```
    const mockFunction = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());

    jest.mock('twilio-flex-ui-core', () => {
        return {
            playInitialAudio: mockFunction,
        };
    });
```